# Is there an alternative for plt.show(0) in python, plt.show(0) no longer works it now shows an error?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running a loop and in each loop I plot the results, previously I used plt.show(0) to freeze the figure and at the end of the all the loops all the subplots appear on one figure. However, plt.show(0) now shows an error.

I have tried plt.ioff() and plt.pause(0.01) but it plots the subplots individually on a new figure.

```
trials = 6
c = 2
r = int(trials / c)
for i in range(1, trials + 1):
    print('Trial {} of {}'.format(i, trials))

    # train NN
    weights, bias, avg_cost_func, m_weights, memory, trained_model, training_data = train_nn(nn_structure, mm_structure, inputs, outputs,                                                                     window_size, horizon, iter_num, eta, momentum)


    # FIGURE 1: plot the ROC curve for training data
    fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 40))
    fig1.suptitle('ROC curve for inhospital mortality classifier training data')

    # subplot
    fig1.add_subplot(r, c, i).plot(avg_cost_func)
    plt.title((('Trail {} of {}'.format(i, trials)), str(np.round(np.average(avg_cost_func), 5))))
    plt.ylabel('Average J')
    plt.xlabel('Iteration number')
    plt.pause(0.01)
    plt.show(0)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=1.5)
plt.show()
```

File "filename.py", line 451, in 
    plt.show(0)

File "C:\Users\n0762538\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 253, in show

return _show(*args, **kw)

TypeError: **call**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Just try using `plt.show()`

Comment: I have problems understanding the desired outcome. What would be wrong with the output if `plt.show(0)` is just removed?

Comment: I would like to see the plots as they are generated and secondly removing plt.show(0) the figures are still generated but on an individual figure for each subplot.

Comment: In that case create the figure outside the loop.